# How do I add another plot to hexbinplot?

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, trellis

I'm trying to plot the location of an incinerator on another plot.

```
# The first plot
hexbinplot(Easting~Northing | Bclass4, 
    BIRTH_NO68, las=1, scales =list(x = list(log = 10, equispaced.log = FALSE)), 
    aspect = 1, bins=50, style="nested.lattice", 
    main="Spatial distribution of birthweights by quartile")
# The second plot
ppp=xyplot(173098~319444, data=BIRTH_NO68, pch=17, cex=15, col="Black")
# Together
hexbinplot(Easting~Northing | Bclass4, BIRTH_NO68, las=1, 
    scales = list(x = list(log = 10, equispaced.log = FALSE)), aspect = 1, 
    bins=50, style="nested.lattice", 
    main="Spatial distribution of birthweights by quartile") + pop
```

All that comes up is the first plot. Here's the [map I'm trying to mark the location of an incinerator on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWYNm.png).

Comment: I don't know if its made more difficult by needing the incinerator location to show on all 4 plots?

Comment: please list the package you are using to for the `hexbinplot` function. It is not part of base R. R has two processes for creating figures: base graphics and grid. If the package you are using uses base graphics, then add `par(mfrow=c(1, 2))` above your first graph for a one row, two column graph panel, or `par(mfrow=c(2, 1))` for a two row, one column panel. See `?par`  for a lot of graphing parameters that you can adjust. For `grid` figures, it a bit more involved.

Comment: the package is hexbin, does that help?

Comment: Looking at the package notes on CRAN, hexbin is based on the `lattice` package, which uses the `grid` graphics engine. http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/web/packages/hexbin/index.html In this case, take a look at `?grid.layout` after loading grid. There are likely questions about this function on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `as.layer` from **latticeExtra** which lets you easily combine single **lattice** plots. Here is some sample code based on the first example provided in `?hexbinplot`.

```
library(hexbin)
library(latticeExtra)

## example taken from ?hexbinplot
mixdata <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(5000),rnorm(5000,4,1.5)),
                      y = c(rnorm(5000),rnorm(5000,2,3)),
                      a = gl(2, 5000))

p1 <- hexbinplot(y ~ x, mixdata, aspect = 1,
                 trans = sqrt, inv = function(x) x^2)

## add points plot to existing hexbinplot
p2 <- xyplot(2.5 ~ 3.5, pch = 24, cex = 3, 
             col = "white", fill = "darkred", lwd = 2)

p1 + as.layer(p2)
```

[image]

Note that you can also accomplish this task in one go without being required to employ **latticeExtra** by simply defining two different `panel` functions inside `hexbinplot`, i.e.

```
hexbinplot(y ~ x, mixdata, aspect = 1,
                 trans = sqrt, inv = function(x) x^2, 
                 panel = function(...) {
                   panel.hexbinplot(...)
                   panel.xyplot(3.5, 2.5, pch = 24, cex = 3, 
                                col = "white", fill = "darkred")
                 })
```